# Shouldn't a entire function be strictly a polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f(z) = a_0 + \cdots a_nz^n + \cdots$ (power series expansion) is an entire function, assume $a_n \neq 0$, then I choose my $ z = a_n$, hence the $n$-th term would then become $a_n^{n+1}$ which would not tend to zero and hence the series diverges.

Note: If $|a_n| < 1,$ then choose $z = 1/a_n$ and hence the $n$-th term would now be $a_n^{1-n}$ which also doesn't tends to 0. Hence the only possibility is $a_n = 0$ which makes $f$ a polynomial.

P.S Using this argument, I would like to prove Liouville's theorem, by choosing $z$ to be large and forcing al $a_i =0$ because of bounded condition.

Comment: When you say choose $z=a_n$, you only choose it for *one* particular $n$, not all of them.

Comment: You can't choose $z = a_n$ or $1/a_n$ for *all* $n\in\Bbb N$!

Comment: When you say you are choosing $z=a_n$, $n$ is fixed. When you later refer that $n$-th term is $a_{n}^{n+1}$, the superscript is now varying $n$, while you are thinking of $a_n$ as a fixed quantity. You are confusing yourself with notations

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your argument is that the $z$ you chose depends on $n$.

Thus your argument gives a sequence $(z_n)_n$ such that the sequence $(a_nz_n^n)_n$ does not tend to $0$. But this is not a contradiction to the condition for convergence you recall.

There are well-known examples of entire functions that are not polynomials, such as $\exp(z)= \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{z^n}{n!}$ or $\sin(z)= \sum_{n\ge 0} \frac{z^{2n+1}(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}$.

You might find it instructive to carry out your argument with one of these examples. Or also to apply the ratio test of convergence to them.